# Interchange positions of two Views within GridLayout (Android)

Tags: android, animation, view, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have programmed a basic gaming App that consists of blocks which can be exchanged by a swipe (similar to CandyCrush). I succeeded in recognizing the swipe gesture but my code that changes the positions of the Views (blocks) within a GridLayout does **only work in the emulator but not on a real device** (Samsung Galaxy S3).

Also **I couldn't find a way of animating the interchange** of the two views. I've added `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the GridLayout XML but it didn't change anything.

Here's my exchanging code:

```
// change to blocks positions in grid layout
GridLayout.LayoutParams sourceParams = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)this.imageView.getLayoutParams();
GridLayout.LayoutParams targetParams = (GridLayout.LayoutParams)otherBlock.imageView.getLayoutParams();

GridLayout.Spec sourceRowSpec = sourceParams.rowSpec;
GridLayout.Spec sourceColumnSpec = sourceParams.columnSpec;
sourceParams.rowSpec = targetParams.rowSpec;
sourceParams.columnSpec = targetParams.columnSpec;
targetParams.rowSpec = sourceRowSpec;
targetParams.columnSpec = sourceColumnSpec;

this.imageView.setLayoutParams(sourceParams);
otherBlock.imageView.setLayoutParams(targetParams);

gameGridLayout.requestLayout();
```

And here's a screenshot of the App:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an index table of your layout, and in your drawing method you run through this index to draw each block. 
Like that:

```
private int [][] index;

void onDraw(Canvas canvas)  {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BLOCK_HEIGHT; i++)  {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_BLOCK_WIDTH; j++)   {
            // Draw block index[i][j]
        }
    }
}

void swapBlock(int blockX, int blockY, int relativePos) {
    int tmpBlock = index[blockY][blockX];
    if (relativePos == AT_LEFT) {
        index[blockY][blockX] = index[blockY][blockX - 1];
        index[blockY][blockX - 1] = tmpBlock;
    }
    // And so on...

}
```

And this index can be helpful all the time, not only for blit.

Comment: I already have an index table that I could draw. I actually draw it but I didn't want to delete all views and redraw every block again just to exchange two blocks. This would cost unnecessary time. Isn't it possible to just redraw those two? Or did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency, modern processors can handle loads of view operations. :)

Comment: I meant, look at zombie tsunami for instance, around 100 views drawn everyframe, plus rotozoom operations on zombies and coins

Comment: OK, thanks. Hope it will be faster on an actual device - the emulator is quite slow. ^^ (Have lend my Android dev phone to a friend ...)

Comment: But what about animation? Is there a way to create a simple linear move animation between the two states automatically? I'm coming from iOS development and there it's as simple as running the changes within a block: `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ /* swap views code */ }]`. Is there something similar available for android?

Comment: You'd have to use ObjectAnimator I think, but i can't help you on that point

Comment: OK, will have to have a look at ObjectAnimator then. Thanks for that direction! :)